# Wpf regarding to Canvas children using index variable doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I have a method which is called from the

> window constructor(Luach is my canvas, Mishbezet is UserControl and
>   mish is dictionary of brushes):

```
        Mishbezet m;
        Luach.Children.Clear();

        double pre_top = 0, top = 0, left = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < NUM; j++)
            {
                m = new Mishbezet();
                m.Width = 80;
                m.Height = 80;
                m.C = Brushes.Transparent;

                Canvas.SetTop(m, top);
                Canvas.SetLeft(m, left);
                Luach.Children.Add(m);
                m.index = new int[4];
                m.index[0] = i;
                m.index[1] = j;
                m.index[2] = i * NUM + j;
                top += 81;
            }
            if (pre_top == 0)
                top = 40;
            else
                top = 0;
            pre_top = top;
            left += 62;
        }

        foreach (var brush in mish)
        {
            ((Mishbezet)(Luach.Children[brush.Key])).Background = brush.Value;

        }
```

The problem is the line

> ((Mishbezet)(Luach.Children[brush.Key])).Background = brush.Value;

When I am using fixed number like `((Mishbezet)(Luach.Children[2])).Background = brush.Value;`
everything is well and it gets its background color but when using the original statement which use int variable as index nothing happens and the UserControl doesn't get background color.
I would appreciate any help and ideas.

Comment: have you any exception thrown at this line? because if there is a key that is out of the children'c collection bounds it will thrown exception and no any child will be updated.

Comment: Can you post the real code you use fixed number inside the loop?

Comment: There isn't exception during this line. when I am using break point I see that the index is for example 2 so when using this fixed number it goes well but with the index variable contains 2 nothing happens.